# match value in one list with another and write value to other list

Tags: c#, linq, list, lambda

I have one list that is written to this class:

```
  public class keyfrs
{
     public keyfrs() { }
     public long regID { get; set; }
     public long ID { get; set; }
     public string county { get; set; }
     public string state { get; set; }
}
List<keyfrs> k = {1,2,3,4}] regID
                 {A,B,C,D}  ID
```

I have another list class like this:

```
 public class states
{
   public states() { }
   public long regID { get; set; }
   public string state { get; set; }
   public string county { get; set; }
}
List<states> s = {1,2,3,4}regID
                 {MA,NY,CT}state
                 {Suffolk,NY,Hampden}county
```

Want to write the county and state to the keyfrs list that matches with the regID from the lists.
What my program does so far is parse in two files and write each one to the different class list it corresponds to. As you can see both classes have a regID column. What I need to do is match the two lists together on regID and write the county and state to the keyfrs list class to then output that list to a new file with these added column in it.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        PARSEkeYfrs();
        parsestateFile();
        matchValues();
          outputFile();

    }
    private static void outputFile()
    {
        string filename = @"c:\keyswCounty.csv";

        using(StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(filename))
        {
            write.WriteLine("RegIF"+","+"ID"+","+"County"+","+"State");
            foreach(keyfrs k in keysandID)
            {
                write.WriteLine(k.regID +"," +k.ID+","+k.county+","+k.state);
            }

        }
    }

    private static void matchValues()
    {
       foreach(keyfrs k in keysandID)
       {


       }
    }

    private static void parsestateFile()
    {
        int a = 0;
       string filename = @"c:\ALLStates.txt";
        using (StreamReader read = new StreamReader(filename))
        {              
                read.ReadLine();
                while (!read.EndOfStream)
                {
                    a++;
                    try{
                    string line = read.ReadLine();
                    string[] splitline = line.Split(',');
                    if(splitline[1]!="")
                    {
                        states s = new states();
                        s.regID = Convert.ToInt64(splitline[0]);
                        s.county = Convert.ToString(splitline[1]);
                        s.state = Convert.ToString(splitline[2]);
                        stateFile.Add(s);
                    }
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                       string.Format("error:{0}" + ex.Message.ToString());
                    }

                }

            }
    }

    private static void PARSEkeYfrs()
    { int a = 0;
        string filename = @"c:\key_frs.csv";
        using (StreamReader read = new StreamReader(filename))
        {              
                read.ReadLine();
                while (!read.EndOfStream)
                {
                    try{
                        a++;
                    string line = read.ReadLine();
                    string[] splitline = line.Split(',');
                    if(splitline[1]!="")
                    {
                        keyfrs k = new keyfrs();
                        k.regID = Convert.ToInt64(splitline[0]);
                        k.ID = Convert.ToInt64(splitline[1]);
                        k.county = "";
                        k.state = "";
                        keysandID.Add(k);
                    }
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        string.Format("error:{0}"+ex.Message.ToString());
                    }

                }

            }


        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
switched the state list to a dictionary and matched the values by the key value pair by using the TryGetValue method.
```